# Personalizar textos con vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Estoy aprendiendo acerca de Vue y esta increíble librería de Vuetify. Pero quería saber si hay alguna forma de cambiar los textos por defecto de algunos componentes.

En este caso, sería de un datatable:

```js
var url = 'recepcion/recepcionIndex.php';

new Vue({

    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data: () => ({

        search: '',
        snackbar: false,
        textSnack: 'Texto del snackbar',
        dialog: false,
        headers: [

        {

            text: 'ID',
            align: 'left',
            sorteable: false,
            value: 'id_celular' 

        },
        {text: 'MARCA', value: 'marca_celular'},
        {text: 'MODELO', value: 'modelo_celular'},
        {text: 'CANTIDAD', value: 'cantidad_celular'},
        {text: 'ACCIONES', value: 'accion', sorteable: false},

        ],
        celulares: [],
        editedIndex: -1,
        editado: {

            id_celular: '',
            marca_celular: '',
            modelo_celular: '',
            cantidad_celular: ''

        },
        defaultItem: {

            id_celular: '',
            marca_celular: '',
            modelo_celular: '',
            cantidad_celular: ''

        }

    }),
    computed:{

        formTitle() {

            return this.editedIndex == -1 ? 'Nuevo Registro' : 'Editar Registro';

        }

    },
    watch:{

        dialog(val) {

            val || this.cancelar()

        },

    },
    created(){

        this.listarCelulares();

    },
    methods: {

        listarCelulares:function() {

            axios.post(url, {opcion: 'listar'}).then(response => {

                this.celulares = response.data;

            });

        },

        subirCelular:function() {

            axios.post(url, {opcion:'subir', marca:this.marca, modelo:this.modelo, cantidad:this.cantidad}).then(response => {

                this.listarCelulares();

            });

            this.marca = "";
            this.modelo = "";
            this.cantidad = 0;

            this.editedIndex = -1;

        },

        editarCelular:function(id, marca, modelo, cantidad) {

            axios.post(url, {opcion:'modificar', id:id, marca:marca, modelo:modelo, cantidad:cantidad}).then(response => {

                this.listarCelulares();

            })

            this.editedIndex = -1;

        },

        eliminarCelular:function(id) {

            axios.post(url, {opcion:'eliminar', id:id}).then(response => {

                this.listarCelulares();

            })

        },

        editar(item) {

            this.editedIndex = this.celulares.indexOf(item);
            this.editado = Object.assign({}, item)

        },

        borrar(item) {

            const index = this.celulares.indexOf(item);

            if (confirm("¿Deseas eliminar este celular?")) {

                this.eliminarCelular(this.celulares[index].id_celular);
                this.snackbar = true;
                this.textSnack = 'Se ha eliminado el celular.';

            }else {

                this.snackbar = true;
                this.textSnack = 'No se ha eliminado el celular.';

            }

        },

        cancelar() {

            this.dialog = false;
            this.editado = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem);
            this.editedIndex = -1;

        },

        guardar() {

            if (this.editedIndex > -1) {

                this.id = this.editado.id_celular;
                this.marca = this.editado.marca_celular;
                this.modelo = this.editado.modelo_celular;
                this.cantidad = this.editado.cantidad_celular;

                if (this.marca == '') {

                    this.snackbar = true;
                    this.textSnack = 'La marca no puede estar vacía.';

                }else if (this.modelo == '') {

                    this.snackbar = true;
                    this.textSnack = 'El modelo no puede estar vacía.';

                }else if (this.cantidad == '' && this.cantidad == 0) {

                    this.snackbar = true;
                    this.textSnack = 'La cantidad no puede estar vacía.';

                }else {

                    this.snackbar = true;
                    this.textSnack = 'Modificación exitosa.';
                    this.editarCelular(this.id, this.marca, this.modelo, this.cantidad);

                }

            }else {

                this.marca = this.editado.marca_celular;
                this.modelo = this.editado.modelo_celular;
                this.cantidad = this.editado.cantidad_celular;

                if (this.marca == '' || this.modelo == '' || this.cantidad == '') {

                    this.snackbar = true;
                    this.textSnack = 'Datos incompletos.';

                }else {

                    this.snackbar = true;
                    this.textSnack = 'Registro exitoso.';
                    this.subirCelular(this.marca, this.modelo, this.cantidad);

                }

            }

            this.cancelar();

        }

    }

})
```

```css
* {

    font-family: 'Roboto';

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
    <title>Tecnología y Productividad</title>

    <!--Estilos vue, fuente Roboto y vuetify.-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons">

</head>
<body>

    <v-app id="app">
        
        <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="celulares" :search="search" class="elevation-3">

            <template v-slot:top>

                <v-system-bar color="indigo darken-2"></v-system-bar>

                <v-toolbar color="indigo">

                    <v-btn class="mx-2" :elevation="10" fab dark color="teal accent-4" @click="dialog = true"><v-icon dark>mdi-plus</v-icon></v-btn>

                    <v-divider class="mx-4" inset vertical></v-divider>

                    <v-toolbar-title class="white--text">Vuetify CRUD</v-toolbar-title>

                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>

                    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="500px">

                        <template v-slot:activador="{on}"></template>

                        <v-card>
                            
                            <v-card-title color="cyan white--text">
                                
                                <span class="headline">{{ formTitle }}</span>

                            </v-card-title>

                            <v-card-text>
                                
                                <v-container>
                                    
                                    <v-row>
                                        
                                        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                                            
                                            <v-text-field v-model="editado.marca_celular" label="Marca"></v-text-field>

                                        </v-col>
                                        
                                        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                                            
                                            <v-text-field v-model="editado.modelo_celular" label="Modelo"></v-text-field>

                                        </v-col>
                                        
                                        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                                            
                                            <v-text-field v-model="editado.cantidad_celular" type="number" step="1" min="0" label="Cantidad"></v-text-field>

                                        </v-col>

                                    </v-row>

                                </v-container>

                            </v-card-text>

                            <v-card-actions>

                                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                                
                                <v-btn color="blue-grey" class="ma-2 white--text" @click="cancelar">Cancelar</v-btn>
                                
                                <v-btn color="teal accent-4" class="ma-2 white--text" @click="guardar">Guardar</v-btn>

                            </v-card-actions>

                        </v-card>

                    </v-dialog>

                </v-toolbar>

                <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
                    
                    <v-text-field v-model="search" append-icon="search" label="Filtrar" single-line hide-details></v-text-field>

                </v-col>

            </template>

            <template v-slot:item.accion="{item}">
                
                <v-btn class="mr-2" fab dark small color="cyan" @click="dialog = true; editar(item)">
                    
                    <v-icon dark>mdi-pencil</v-icon>

                </v-btn>
                
                <v-btn class="mr-2" fab dark small color="error" @click="borrar(item)">
                    
                    <v-icon dark>mdi-delete</v-icon>

                </v-btn>

            </template>

        </v-data-table>

        <template>
            
            <div class="text-center ma-2">
                
                <v-snackbar v-model="snackbar">
                    
                    {{ textSnack }}

                    <v-btn color="info" text @click="snackbar = false">Cerrar</v-btn>

                </v-snackbar>

            </div>

        </template>

    </v-app>

    <!--Llamar axios.-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

    <!--Scripts vuw y vuetify.-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Cuando no existen datos, muestra 'No data available'. La idea sería cambiarlo a 'No hay datos disponibles'. O en la parte de la paginación, 'Rows per page', sería 'Filas por página'.

Espero estar dándome a entender. Sería traducirlo, o en su defecto, personalizar todos esos textos.

Comment: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/internationalization/ google es tu solucion.. y la documentacion de ellos mucho mas...

Answer (score 0):

Si sólo lo necesitas hacerlo en esta tabla establece la propiedad `no-data-text`

```
<v-data-table no-data-text="No hay datos disponibles"> </v-data-table>
```

Si vas a requerir traducir al español en todo tu proyecto mejor configura el plugin para hacerlo en automático, revisa la [documentación](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/internationalization/) sobre como hacerlo.